# How to fix "expected identifier or '(' in C compilation?

Tags: cs50

I am new to coding and I keep getting stuck in the first few lines of code and I cannot figure out why. This is what I have so far:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void);
int n;
{
    printf("Minute: ");
    int n = get_int();
}
```

I am getting this message when I try to compile the code:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the main function. You should only define it. It will be called when the program is executed (it is the "entry point").

To define it, remove the semicolon after 
int main(void)

You can also remove that void keyword

Then move that line down, between
int n; and the { that comes after it

Additionally, you're declaring the n variable twice. After you fix the first error, the compiler will complain about this one. Remove one of the declarations then.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the semicolon after **int main(void)** and move the variable declaration for n within the braces.  Here is the correct code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printf("Minute: ");
    int n = get_int();
}
```